# cakephp 3.0 pagination example

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add a row in existing table I want to make it unique when I am trying to alter in phpmyadmin it says #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'mobile'

What code will help me suggest

Comment: It looks like there is a duplicate entry on your table. You need to fix that first.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and show us the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you have two entries which both have '0' in the `mobile` column. You can't force the column to be UNIQUE because there's non-unique data in their now. The solution is to resolve the conflict, but whether that's a good idea and how exactly to do so depends on your database design. The act of doing it is rather simple (just edit that row and assign a new value for 'mobile'), but depending on your design that could damage some data.

So without knowing the details, I can only caution you to not destroy any data or relations.

If you don't have a primary or unique key in that table, phpMyAdmin doesn't show the '"grid edit" feature, so if that's the case you can either write a little SQL to update the row directly, or temporarily add a new column, make it an autoincrementing primary key, do the edit through the phpMyAdmin interface, then remove the temporary autoincrement column (that's what I'd do; I just tested it and it took me about 30 seconds to add the column and key, edit a row, and delete the temporary column).